# How to Remove Space Additionally to the Special Chars?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

in my functions.php if have this code:

```
echo '<a href="'.preg_replace('/\s/','-',$search).'-keyword1.html">'.urldecode($search).'</a>';
```

this removes the special chars..

but how can i additonally add remove space and replace it with - and remove "

so, if someone types in **"yo! here"** i want **yo-here**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php

$str = '"yo! here"';

$str = preg_replace( array('/[^\s\w]/','/\s/'),array('','-'),$str);

var_dump($str); // prints yo-here

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace a run of unwanted characters with a single dash, then you can use something like this:

```
preg_replace('/\W+/', '-', $search);
```

To remove surrounding quotes, and then replace any other junk with dashes, try this:

```
$no_quotes = preg_replace('/^"|"$/', '', $search);
$no_junk = preg_replace('/\W+/', '-', $no_quotes);
```

Comment: For the OP's input: '"yo! here"' this will produce '-yo-here-'

Answer (score 1):

This will replace multiple spaces / "special" chars with a single hyphen. If you don't want that, remove the "+".

You might want to trim off any trailing hyphens, should something end with an exclamation point / other.

`<?php
preg_replace("/\W+/", "-", "yo! here   check this out");
?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove any **non-words**:

```
preg_replace('/\W/', '-', $search);
```